# How is reputation counted on chat?

Tags: support, bug, chat

I want to know how reputation is counted on [Chat Stack Exchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com). In the [users page sorted by all reputation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=reputation). It shows

[image]

We all know Jon Skeet has 612k rep.

How is reputation counted on chat?

Comment: That's weird. It says he has 448k rep when he really has 612k, and it says he has 100 gold badges when he really has 222. Caching?

Comment: @Doorknob What does it show for you?

Comment: I refreshed the user profile for Jon Skeet from the parent site, and that did fix the reputation. Why it was so completely wrong I don't know. My best guess would be that rep is not synced when a user doesn't visit chat.

Comment: @MadScientist I guess it was a bug and it has been fixed. Same for me.

Comment: @MadScientist A bit of a long shot, but if no one bothered to refresh his chat.stackexchange page since around January last year, it would seem to be a caching issue.

Comment: Also, is it just me, or is it summing up reputation, but not badges?

Comment: @DennisMeng Not just you. me too

Comment: Look at the "Last Post" dates, I guess it updates your chat profile _when you enter the chat_. Which Jon hasn't done in quite a bit.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That's what I thought too, but Jon Skeet's rep was "only" 383k or so when he last chatted. Unless you're saying he popped in a few times and didn't say anything?

Comment: Mysteriously that page has updated now. I suspect the 448K is 383K SO + ~40K MSO + ~2k * the other sites.

Comment: @Flexo Yes. I guess it has been fixed but the badges aren't summed up. some one already asked it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200509/chat-stackexchange-reputation-counted-across-all-sites-but-badge-totals-are-not)

Comment: Yeah, I posted the question after we determined it wasn't just me.

Comment: His rep was 448k on January 9th, 2012. See [his network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=reputation) and use the fancy tooltips.