# chat.stackexchange reputation counted across all sites, but badge totals are not

Tags: bug, chat

After helping out a bit with [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200507/how-is-reputation-counted-on-chat) question, I couldn't help but notice that when listing users on chat.stackexchange, the reputation is the total reputation across all sites when last computed, but the badges appear to only be the badges on the *parent site*.

Using Jon Skeet's as an example:

[image]

he has 687k across all sites (not just Stack Overflow...at least, not yet), but the 222 gold badges and 3626 silver badges refer to his totals on Stack Overflow *only*. By my count, he has 25 golds and 185 silver badges across the other sites, so it should show 247 and 3811, respectively.

Is it possible to also make badge counts cumulative (like on flairs)?

Comment: A while ago [this wasn't practical](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/77?m=736759#736759), but the way chat gets this information these days might make this easier.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense.

Comment: (Also, things get confusing if you actually look on profiles; not only is the reputation/badge tallying the same; the placement makes it look like both are supposed to be parent site only. Here's [mine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ORk82.png) as an example.)

Comment: Well, it's been about a year, and I guess Jon proved me right; he appears to be north of 700k now.